# Automating a SQL Restore - but delayed by 24 hours

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to script the following process and would be grateful for any guidance in achieving it!

We have a live database which is backed up every night (SQL 2008 R2). We have a 3rd party which requires access to the database but management have decided they can have access to a time-delayed copy instead. So I have been tasked with restoring the previous nights backup to another SQL instance, complete with login information to which the 3rd party can access without impacting the live database.

I believe a script could perform the task, except the backup file name is not constant (i.e databasename_2015_02_15_223005_3661110) and I can't figure out a way of automating a restore without knowing the backup name. We keep 3 days of full backups on the server before they are archived.

Instead should I be looking at either snapshots or replication to produce the 24 hour delayed copy?

Comment: Are you able to query the management views to get the filenames? I would look at the BackupSet and BackupMediaFamily views

Comment: Why can't you just calculate the backup name in the script? Sounds like you are so close to success and are now giving up on restores.

Comment: Thanks for the comment both - Apologies I should should have stated - I'm an accidental-DBA (6 weeks in the role so far due to the company not replacing the DBA who left) so I am cramming as much reading in as I can, understanding as much as I can! My TSQL isn't great so I am cannibalising scripts, and seeing if they perform what I need on my testlab server. It would be simple if I could get away with a 23 hour gap, that way I could just restore the latest backup prior to the live system backing itself up again! I'll go and do some reading up on BackupSet and BackupMediaFamily views. Thanks